# C++ Specific override of template class member function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I would like to have a class that implement multiple interfaces of same template class as follow:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual void foo(const T&) = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class A{};
class B{};

class Derived : public Interface<A>, public Interface<B> { /* ... */ };
```

Here class Derived would have methods

```cpp
void Derived::Interface<A>::foo(const A&)
void Derived::Interface<B>::foo(const B&)
void Derived::Interface<A>::bar()
void Derived::Interface<B>::bar()
```

The first 2 are no problem, but the last 2 are ambiguous.
In call context it is ok for me to do:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.Derived::Interface<A>::bar();
    d.Derived::Interface<B>::bar();
}
```

The problem is overriding specific methods.
I thought I could just write:

```cpp
class Derived : public Interface<A>, public Interface<B>
{
public:
    inline void Interface<A>::bar() override { /* ... */ }
    inline void Interface<B>::bar() override { /* ... */ }
};
```

But the linker says it does not find method definition for methods referenced in main: `d.Derived::Interface<A>::bar()` & `d.Derived::Interface<A>::bar()`.

I succeeded to do it, but I needed to add a "default" method override:

```cpp
class Derived : public Interface<A>, public Interface<B>
{
public:
    inline void bar() override {}
};

void Derived::Interface<A>::bar() { /* ... */ }
void Derived::Interface<B>::bar() { /* ... */ }
```

**EDIT:** with MSVC compiler the above code compile, but with clang/gcc you need to specify `template<>` in front of `bar` method specializations.

Now, the main compile and run correctly as intended.

**QUESTION:** Is it possible to not add this "default" override ? Because I will never need to just call `d.bar()` and thus the implementation is empty and might lead to confusion.

Thank you ☺

Comment: If you define just `bar`, it will override both (since they have the same signature).

Comment: "compile and run correctly as intended." I somehow doubt it.  `Bar::Interface<A>::bar()` (or whatever you call this) cannot be called through an `Interface<A>` pointer or reference. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ebP887s6z).

Comment: MInor point: `inline` on a function definition that's inside a class definition is redundant.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  
@DavisHerring yes but the point is that `Derived::Interface<A>::bar` & `Derived::Interface<B>::bar` have different implementation.
@n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I had a few copy/paste error in the question that are fixed now, please see [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yhb3KxTxa)
@PeteBecker yes indeed

Comment: I know what your typos are, I fixed them in my demo. Your error is not a typo, but a misconception. `template<> void Derived::Interface<A>::bar()` doesn't override anything. It's a specialization of `Interface<T>::bar` for `T=A`. You could specialize the whole `Interface<T>` for `T=A` and have exactly the same effect, except then you don't need to override `bar` in `Derived` because these specializations will no longer be abstract.

Comment: If you think `template<> void Derived::Interface<A>::bar() ` overrides something, try to create another class `Derived2` in the same file. Can you do `template<> void Derived2::Interface<A>::bar()`?

Comment: Indeed, since initially I thought I could override specific `bar` method inherited from `Interface<A>` & `Interface<B>` and since MSVC did not warned me of template specification missing (`template<>`) I thought it was overriding but it is not. Since it is specialization I do not need to make `bar` method virtual. What I want to achieve is post below as an alternative answer

Answer (score 1):

A similar situation is discussed in detail in one of the Stroustrup's books. His solution is to "rename" one or both functions this way:

```
class InterfaceA : public Interface<A> {
   void bar() override { barA(); }
   virtual void barA() = 0; 
      // or call Interface<A>::bar() if it has an implementation
};

class InterfaceB : public Interface<B> {
   void bar() override { barB(); }
   virtual void barB() = 0;
      // or call Interface<B>::bar() if it has an implementation
};
```

Now when you call `bar` through an `Interface<A>` pointer or reference, it will call `Interface<A>::bar`, which will call `barA`, which will call whatever override of `barA` your concrete class has. Same about `Interface<B>`. `Derived` "renames" `bar` inherited from `Interface<A>` to `barA`, so if you have a `Derived` pointer or reference, you need to call that. Calls to `bar` will be ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am actually not using it as an polymorphic interface: I will never have a `Interface<A>` (or `Interface<B>`) pointer/ref calling directly the method. The call will be indirect (similar to the main function I wrote).

That being said, the solution you propose would do the trick and I might consider it, thanks again

Comment: This is what I suspected after looking at your attempt. If you don't use a polymorphic interface, then don't create a polymorphic interface. Just remove `Interface::bar` and possibly the whole `Interface`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. I realize I was not overriding `bar` method but specializing the template (also MSVC not seeing that as an error ...)

What I wanted to achieve is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class Interface
{
public:
    void bar();
};

class A
{
public:
    static const std::string& msg()
    {
        static std::string aMsg = "A";
        return aMsg;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    static const std::string& msg()
    {
        static std::string bMsg = "B";
        return bMsg;
    }
};

class Derived : public Interface<A>, public Interface<B>
{
};

template<> void Derived::Interface<A>::bar() { std::cout << A::msg() << std::endl; }
template<> void Derived::Interface<B>::bar() { std::cout << B::msg() << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.Interface<A>::bar();
    d.Interface<B>::bar();
}
```

The output is:

> A
> B

Now I won't have a `bar` method doing nothing and if there is no specialization of `bar` method for Derived class there will be a link error forcing the developer to implement/specialize the method.
Thanks

Comment: `Derived::Interface<A>::bar` is a misleading name. It is the same entity as `Interface<A>::bar`.